# Reg exp шаблон ввода

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Какой шаблон регулярного выражения у этого примера? `0-10`

Comment: Укажите все данные

Comment: 0-10, как проверить соответствует ли ввод данному шаблону? 0-10

Comment: в смысле данному шаблону 0-10? Вы хотите точно знать, ввёл пользователь строку '0-10' или что???

Comment: Например если пользователь ввел 20-100 это правильно. Если он ввел к пример, 0-asd, asd-10, 20-, -20 это неправильно. То есть если формат соответствует числам с тире то это правильно.

Comment: Так вы бы так нормально и писали в вопросе. Вам надо к экстрасенсам обращаться.

Comment: так , например - `^\d+\-\d+$`

Comment: Тогда пишите яснее, шаблон: `^[\d-]+$`.

Comment: @Гром Супиев  `'~\d+(?:[\d-]+)*~'`

Comment: '~\d+(?:[\d-]+)*~' Вот этот вариант подходит, но проблема в том что буквы тоже проходят, как сделать так чтобы проходили только цифры?

Comment: @Гром Супиев попробуйте такой вариант: `$str = '0-10';

if (!preg_match('~^\d+(?:-\d+)?$~', $str)) {
    die('Ошибка!');
}`

Comment: @Эдуард, БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО! Оставьте ответ, я его выберу правильным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex-шаблон будет иметь следующий вид:

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?$
```

Он будет соответствовать началу строки, за которым следует обязательное вхождение одной или более цифр, за которыми следует не обязательная последовательность символов тире и чисел, после которых следует символ конца строки.

В сочетании с PHP всё будет выглядеть так:

```
$str = '0-10'; 

if (!preg_match('~^\d+(?:-\d+)?$~', $str)) {
    die('Ошибка!');
}
```